# python google-cloud-speech: SSL error through gRPC proxy

Tags: python, ssl, ssl-certificate, grpc, google-cloud-speech

I'm developing an integration with Google STT (Speech to Text) API in which we had to develop a gRPC "proxy" written in Python in front of it.

Now we are trying to add integration tests to invoke this "proxy", but we are experiencing SSL errors:

> E0530 16:43:40.566553587   12452 ssl_transport_security.cc:1495] Handshake failed with fatal error SSL_ERROR_SSL: error:1000007d:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED.

The error occurs only when the tests call STT through the "proxy". It works as expected when calling STT directly (without the "proxy").

We are using the python client `speech.SpeechClient` in tests to invoke STT and replace the `api_endpoint` param to invoke our "proxy" instead.

Is there any way to disable SSL checks? Since it's only for testing purposes SSL is not required.